# Javascript search string for numbers regex maybe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a string like

> :21::22::24::99:

And I want to find say if `:22:` is in said string. But is there a means of searching a string like above for one like I want to match it to with javascript, and if there is, does it involve regex magic or is there something else? Either way not sure how to do it, more so if regex is involved.

Comment: `':21::22::24::99:'.indexOf(':22:') > -1`?

Comment: If you know the numbers will always be separated with colons you can just use `if(yourString.indexOf(":22:") != -1){/*number found*/}`. (You don't need jQuery.)

Comment: I was thinking indexOf unfortunately, its not supported in older browsers, which is a partial concern not huge but exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the regular expression you need:

```
function findNumberInString(num, s) {
    var re = new RegExp(':' + num + ':');
    return re.test(s);
}

var s = ':21::22::24::99';
var n = '22';

findNumberInString(n, s);  // true
```

or just use match (though test is cleaner to me)

```
!!s.match(':' + n + ':');  // true
```

#### Edit

Both the above use regular expressions, so a decimal ponit (.) will come to represent any character, so "4.1" will match "461" or even "4z1", so better to use a method based on `String.prototype.indexOf` just in case (unless you *want* "." to represent any character), so per Blender's comment:

```
function findNumberInString(num, s) {
    return s.indexOf(':' + num + ':') != -1;
}
```

Comment: Might want to handle if someone wants to find the number `4.2`.

Comment: nope don't need to worry about that in this case these numbers will always be round or ceil without decimal.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. May not be a requirement now, but good reason to go with `String.prototype.indexOf` rather than anything using a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

like this:

```
aStr = ':21::22::24::99:';
if(aStr.indexOf(':22:') != -1){
    //':22:' exists in aStr
}
else{
    //it doesn't
}
```